# How to create a section with a darker background

Tags: cv

I'm writing my CV in latex, and I'm  using an online (fake) cv as template.

I have not been able yet to give a dark background to a specific area, like in the image I attach:

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

This I'm using:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{
    {images/PDFs/}
    {images/JPGs/}
    {images/PNGs/}
}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\usepackage{multicol}
```

Comment: The `framed` package  defined a  `shaded` environment, for which you can choose the background colour. However, don't forget your CV must remain readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but this is the first came to my mind. You may use a mini-page environment for this purpose. Here is the MWE. Make mini-page frames and put the content with the background you like inside.

```
% pdfLaTeX - TL2022

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red!80!black}{blue!20!white}{%
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\noindent\fcolorbox{blue!80!black}{red!20!white}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\noindent\fcolorbox{blue!80!black}{red!20!white}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]